# How to automate testing for Virtual Reality Application?

Tags: automated-tests, virtual-reality, webvr

I am curious if anybody has tried automating tests for a virtual reality application or knows of any resources that might be useful? I've done some searching and at the moment nothing too obvious is standing out.
From previous work experience I feel there might be some possibility with Visual Regression on the UI side of the app and for the interaction side (moving around etc) Unity Test Runner, although I've never used/heard of it and just come across it whilst reading up.

Not sure how any of these would be implemented but just throwing the ideas out there and if anybody has any knowledge on this it would be nice to hear. Thanks!